# Cómo validar longitud de variables

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario login que envía **usuario** y **clave** lo que se procesa con este código:

```
<?php
    if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && ($_POST['action'] === 'login')) {
        if (isset($_POST['usuario']) && isset($_POST['clave'])) {

            $usuariodao = new UsuarioDAO();
            $user = $usuariodao->login($$_POST['usuario'], $$_POST['clave']);

            if($user->getUsuario()) {
                header('Location: principal.php');
                exit;
            } else {
                $tpl = new Plantilla();
                $tpl->assign('errorLogin', 'Usuario y/o Clave incorrectos');
                $tpl->display('index.tpl.php');
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            $tpl = new Plantilla();
            $tpl->assign('errorLogin', 'Acceso no Autorizado');
            $tpl->display('index.tpl.php');
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        $tpl = new Plantilla();
        $tpl->assign('errorLogin', 'Acceso no Permitido');
        $tpl->display('index.tpl.php');
        exit;
    }
?>
```

Cómo puedo validar que los campos **usuario** y **clave** no tengan una longitud mayor de 10 caracteres?
Y si es posible simplificar los dos primeros condicionales ***if***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo con [La Documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strlen.php) puedes validar la longitud de strings haciendo us de la función`int strlen(string)`.

Esta obtiene un entero que devuelve la longitud de un string.

De manera que si

```
$Usuario = 'Manolo';

if(strlen($Usuario) > 10)
{
    //El usuario no es valido
}
```

---

```
    <?php
    if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && ($_POST['action'] === 'login')) {
        if (isset($_POST['usuario']) && isset($_POST['clave'])) {

            if(strlen($_POST['usuario']) > 15 && strlen($_POST['clave']) > 15)
            {
                //Error
            }
            else
            {
              // Proceso de logueo

            $usuariodao = new UsuarioDAO();
            $user = $usuariodao->login($$_POST['usuario'], $$_POST['clave']);

            if($user->getUsuario()) {
                header('Location: principal.php');
                exit;
            } else {
                $tpl = new Plantilla();
                $tpl->assign('errorLogin', 'Usuario y/o Clave incorrectos');
                $tpl->display('index.tpl.php');
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            $tpl = new Plantilla();
            $tpl->assign('errorLogin', 'Acceso no Autorizado');
            $tpl->display('index.tpl.php');
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        $tpl = new Plantilla();
        $tpl->assign('errorLogin', 'Acceso no Permitido');
        $tpl->display('index.tpl.php');
        exit;
    }
   }}}
?>
```

Comment: Se me ocurre algo así **if((strlen($txtUsuario) > 15) && (strlen($txtClave) > 15))** pero cómo lo pongo para que caiga dentro de las condicionales?

Comment: @Piropeator Mmmmm, revisa mi post y dime si esto es lo que quieres lograr

Comment: Claro, esa es la idea pero cómo inserto esta condicón dentro de toda mi estructura? Tendré que crear otro else ?

Comment: @Piropeator Bien, mira ahora

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear otra método ejemplo:

```
function countLong($var, $max)
{
  if(strlen($var) >$max){
    return strlen($var) . " > " . $max;
  }
  return strlen($var) . "< " . $max ;
}

echo countLong("usuario", 5);
```

buena suerte